# Docker volume name changed when running stack after changing directory name

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I am experimenting with docker on windows and creating a stack for the same.

I just found that when i use docker-compose up -d, docker volume are created with the name like foldername_volumename.

I have a working app for the stack under one folder and just want to change the folder name. But found that while I changed it, it prevent me to use the same volume that was previously used.

I have some configurations and data that I will lose if i will move to another volume name.

Is there any way to reuse the same volume but still able to change the folder name?

What is the best practice?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `external: true` to let docker compose know that it does not need to create the volume, it already exists (and therefore, the folder name will not be prepended).

```
version: '3.2'

volumes:
  mydata:
    external: true

services:
  test:
    image: alpine
    volumes: 
    - mydata:/data
```

[External volumes documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#external)

Answer (score 0):

The volume name is based on the *project name*. By default project name is based on the containing folder's name, but you can override it by doing `docker-compose -p yourprojectname`. So if you do that you can get consistent volume names regardless of containing folder name.